# how do I use the new OpenXR VR view?

Tags: 3d-view

I checked the blender documentation on "VR Scene Inspection" here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/3d_view/vr_scene_inspection.html

I enabled the VR Scene Inspection addon:

[image: VR addon enabled in settings]

But now I still don't have the VR tab available:

[image: blender viewport tabs without VR tab]

I tested that OpenXR works by running `hello_xr -g Vulkan -ff Hmd -vc Stereo -s Stage -v` first. It seems currently the SteamVR beta doesn't support OpenGL yet but I don't think that's the issue because I haven't seen any error logs about anything anywhere yet.

I ran blender with -d to check for debug logs and looked in the "Info" view, however there are no logs related to VR/OpenXR. I also tried running with --debug-xr but that was not a recognized flag and it tried to open a file called --debug-xr.

Has anyone gotten the VR scene inspection working in Blender or is there some more info on this yet? I'm running stable Blender 2.83.0 installed from the normal Arch community repo together with the new SteamVR beta providing OpenXR support (working in hello_xr) and I've got OpenXR headers, layers, loader and utils version 1.0.8.r26.g3e40561-1 installed.